# Как сформировать GET запрос

Tags: javascript, api, get, request, axios

Есть некий get запрос https://any-request/api/search(:format). Не могу понять как формировать последнюю часть запроса (:format) потому что на выходе должно получиться что-то типа https://any-request/api/search?list=1&q=%7B%7D
Плес подскажите туплю чот.

Answer (score 0):

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Структура_URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_URL)

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Кодирование_URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL)

Изучайте вышеприведенные ссылки, там есть ответ на все ваши вопросы.

Comment: спасибо большое